# Freezing screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I got kivy label that I am updating in other class(not app or something) from another function
by this code:

```
App.get_running_app().root.screens[3].fingerSensorStatus = "Place Finger"
```

fingerSensorStatus variable is text that in the kv file looks like

```
Label:
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.3 , 'y': 0.6 }
            text: root.fingerSensorStatus
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.4
```

This cause to my screen to freeze and turning it to black.
So I saw this solution in the App class:

```
class AddFingerWindow(Screen):

    namee = ObjectProperty(None)
    passwd = ObjectProperty(None)
    fingerSensorStatus = StringProperty("")
    
    
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 1)

    def callback(self):
        fingerSensorStatus = db.FsensorStatus
```

But I am getting

"NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

Ive tried to solve it with:

```
def __init__(self):
        namee = ObjectProperty(None)
        passwd = ObjectProperty(None)
        fingerSensorStatus = StringProperty("")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 1)
```

but got **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'.

How I can solve this(I mean the freezing screen)?

Answer (score 0):

Properties (ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ...) must be declared at class level - i.e. *outside* your `__init__`.

Python code that you want to run when a class is instantiated should be declared during `__init__`, so but the `Clock.schedule_interval` there.

Note that this isn't an arbitrary distinction, your Clock code doesn't make sense at class level because not only is self not defined but it has no useful value it could take - remember that this code is run when the class definition is interpreted, before any instances exist. In contrast, the Property objects are python descriptors that must live at class level as they define some details of how every instance will behave.

Comment: So how can I use Clock.schedule_interval with function that updates the same class property? (fingerSensorStatus)

Comment: Well, what part of doing that do you not understand? You need to pass a function that does the thing you want. One of your code snippets is close, but the `callback` needs to set `self.fingerSensorStatus` rather than just `fingerSensorStatus` (which just defines a local variable that does nothing), and also will receive an extra argument from the clock that you can ignore.